# Bash - properly retry a command when set -e is active

Tags: bash, shell

I have two shell scripts:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

travis_retry() {
  local result=0
  local count=1
  while [ $count -le 3 ]; do
    [ $result -ne 0 ] && {
      echo -e "\n\033[33;1mThe command \"$@\" failed. Retrying, $count of 3.\033[0m\n" >&2
    }
    ("$@" && result=0) || result=1
    echo "result: $result"
    if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "success"
    else
      echo "fail"
    fi
    [ $result -eq 0 ] && break
    count=$(($count + 1))
    sleep 1
  done

  [ $count -eq 3 ] && {
    echo "\n\033[33;1mThe command \"$@\" failed 3 times.\033[0m\n" >&2
  }

  return $result
}

travis_retry ./fail.sh
```

(Mostly from https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-rubies/blob/build/build.sh#L10)

The other one, `./fail.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "gonna fail"
sleep 5
exit 1
```

It properly retries the failures, but when i rewrite fail.sh to exit with 0, and echo "gonna win", it displays "gonna win", but still reports that the result is 0.

Let me show an example output:

```
gonna fail
result: 1
fail

The command "./fail.sh" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.

gonna fail
./fail.sh: line 4: xit: command not found
result: 1
fail

The command "./fail.sh" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.

gonna win
result: 1
fail
```

How can I achieve the desired result, so if the `fail.sh` starts to report exit code 0, the other script also succeeds?

As far as I can conclude, this line has the issue:
`("$@" && result=0) || result=1`

But I can't see why it doesn't assign 0 upon success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use parenthesis in expression:

```bash
("$@" && result=0) || result=1
```

Parenthesis create a sub shell, so `result=0` is executed in this sub shell, not in your main script process.

```bash
"$@" && result=0 || result=1
```

works fine